Comsol Multiphysics 5.6 does not work on kubuntu 24.04
I have Comsol Multiphysics 5.6 installed on Kubuntu 22.04 and it works fine. When i install it on kubuntu 24.04 it does not work, I think this problem is not specific for Ubuntu flavors, because I have it for other recent distros too.
Does anyone know the reason behind this problem or if there any solution.
Best regards.

Run it from terminal, and post the output

On their homepage only Ubuntu  20.04 and 22.04 is mentioned. Try asking their support, somewhere on same site, about plans or workarounds for supporting newest Ubuntu release.
